# correct use of select and js together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use select to give users a option of two things. 1 option is owner the other option is is non owner. i want to be able to ask them different questions if they are owner or not. i want them to be able to enter there answers numerically 1-10, and give them feedback based on the answers. ill try to make it super clear if i can. one question with two options. when that is selected the owner or non owner questions will be asked and added i have include a fiddle with what i have. I am all over the place, and have no idea don't mind me. if someone can show me on that works that would be great!!! change anything in it, just want it to work.  http://jsfiddle.net/philyphil/CcVsz/11/

```
<select class="myOptions">
<option data-val="" selected>Pick an option</option>
<option data-val="owner">Owner</option>
<option data-val="not-owner">Not Owner</option>
</select>
```

Comment: calm down and be precise

Comment: Super Clear means not understandable...

Comment: In your linked demo when I change the `select` option, the list changes to show different checkboxes. What's the problem you're having?

Comment: sorry on this all day still not getting any where. if i select owner and put,1,1,1 it will do what i want...but if i use non owner and do the same nothing.

Comment: i was trying to use a if statement to say if owner add impute/question 1,2 and 3 else if add 4,5 and 6. and give them impute back like i have it set up now. it don't matter to me how i do it.. i will do it the best way anyone says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest, to handle the summation, changing the jQuery to:

```
$('#butt').click(function () {

    /* this gets an array of the numbers contained within visible
       input elements */
    var nums = $('.list input:visible').map(function () {
        return parseInt(this.value, 10);
    }),
    // initialises the total variable:
        total = 0;
    /* iterates over the numbers contained within the array,
       adding them to the 'total' */
    for (var i = 0, len = nums.length; i < len; i++) {
        total += nums[i];
    }

    var msg = '';

    if (isNaN(total)) {
        msg = 'Input three numbers, please...';
    } else if (total < 30) {
        msg = "That's bad, should be higher...";
    } else if (total > 40) {
        msg = "That's bad, should be lower...";
    } else {
        msg = "You got it... Nice work.";
    }


    $('#output').text(msg);

});
```

And also not using the `id` attribute to select the elements to sum, instead using `class`-names:

```
<div class="list owner">
    <p>a</p>
    <input class="numbers" type="text" size="2" />
    <br/>
    <p>b</p>
    <input class="numbers" type="text" size="2" />
    <br/>
    <p>c</p>
    <input class="numbers" type="text" size="2" />
    <br/>
    <!-- questions for owners -->
</div>
<div class="list not-owner">
    <p>x</p>
    <input class="numbers" type="text" size="2" />
    <br/>
    <p>y</p>
    <input class="numbers" type="text" size="2" />
    <br/>
    <p>z</p>
    <input class="numbers" type="text" size="2" />
    <br/>
    <!-- questions for non-owners -->
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/CcVsz/20/).

To test if someone is, or says they are, the owner:

```
var total = 0,
    isOwner = $.trim($('.myOptions option:selected').val()) === 'owner';
if (isOwner) {
    console.log("It's the owner");
}
```

The above jQuery is coupled to a `select` element in which the `option` elements have values:

```
<select class="myOptions">
    <option value="-1" data-val="" selected>Pick an option</option>
    <option value="owner" data-val="owner">Owner</option>
    <option value="not-owner" data-val="not-owner">Not Owner</option>
</select>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/CcVsz/21/).

References:

- [`jQuery.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).
- [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
- [`:selected` selector](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/).
- [`:visible` selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).

Comment: Dave question if i wanted to add another if statement to this... example owner answers with a 9, b 2, c 9  and i wanted to say 21 is ok but b 2 is very bad.  with just js i would do something this like if(total>21 & a,b,c<5){console log ("good mes");console.log("b is bad mes ")}

Comment: it looks like you used $('.list input:visible').each(function(){
        total += parseInt(this.value,10); to add all of the answers together. thanks a lot I appreciate it.

Comment: or anyone who can help, dave your answer worked the best for me... but question, i want to be able to have access to the input from each answer...you answer only gives me the total...iwant something like var $boxOne = $('#box1'); var k1 = parseInt($boxOne.val(), 10);  say for owner if question two they 1-10 they say 2 i would like to be able to say very good,very bad. now it's set you where there all added and i dont think i can access them separate.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector was wrong inside click handler for 'not owner' btw IDs must be unique on context page. Best way is to use class instead of IDs and check for visible boxes:

```
$('.myOptions').change(function(){
  $('.list').removeClass('active')
  .filter('.' + $('.myOptions').children('option:selected').attr('data-val'))
  .addClass('active');
});

/* want to say if owner do this 
when I un-comment this it breaks
var qbc = $('#owner')
var c = $('#myOptions')

if $(c == qbc){
    prompt("worked!!!!")
}
*/


$('#butt').click(function () {
    var $boxOne = $('.box:visible').eq(0);
var k1 = parseInt($boxOne.val(), 10);
var $boxTwo = $('.box:visible').eq(1);
    var k2 = parseInt($boxTwo.val(), 10);

    var $boxThree = $('.box:visible').eq(2);
    var k3 = parseInt($boxThree.val(), 10);


    var total = k1 + k2 + k3;

    var msg = '';

    if (isNaN(total)) {
        msg = 'Input three numbers, please...';
    } else if (total < 30) {
        msg = "That's bad, should be higher...";
    } else if (total > 40) {
        msg = "That's bad, should be lower...";
    } else {
        msg = "You got it... Nice work.";
    }


    $('#output').text(msg);   

});

/* else i will change question number and do same thing */
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CcVsz/19/)